# How to change a specific (this) button class when click on. Using Vue.js 2.0

Tags: class, bind, vuejs2, vue.js

When clicked the any of the buttons they are all turns active. So what i want is just the clicked one should be changed.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#toolBtns',
 data: {
  isActive: false
 },
 computed: {
  activeClass: function () {
   return {
    active: this.isActive
   };
  }
 }
});
```

```html
<div class="btn-group" role="group" id="toolBtns">
  <button class="btn" type="button" @click="isActive = !isActive" :class="activeClass">Btn1</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" @click="isActive = !isActive" :class="activeClass">Btn2</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" @click="isActive = !isActive" :class="activeClass">Btn3</button></div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably need a variable to find which button is currently selected. And you can use that variable to dynamically bind correct class: with : `:class="{active: activeBtn === 'btn1' }"`.

Benefit of this approach is you have only one variable instead of array to save which button is currently selected, so you dont have to iterate on the array everytime you select a button.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#toolBtns',
  data: {
   activeBtn:''
  }
 });
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="toolBtns">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" id="toolBtns">
  <button class="btn" type="button" @click="activeBtn = 'btn1'" :class="{active: activeBtn === 'btn1' }">Btn1</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" @click="activeBtn = 'btn2'" :class="{active: activeBtn === 'btn2' }">Btn2</button>
  <button class="btn" type="button" @click="activeBtn = 'btn3'" :class="{active: activeBtn === 'btn3' }">Btn3</button></div>
</div>
```

See working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9y02qo6a/).

Comment: Thank you Saurabh,
I will do some research on the method you have suggested and I will try to share the result here.

The above situation is still problematic. So it did not work.

Comment: See the comment bellow together with a working fiddle :)

Comment: Thank you @Saurabh. Yes, we can say that this solution is more effective in the current situation.

Comment: @Saurabh Maybe you can help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566362/how-can-i-add-button-selected-if-clicked-on-the-box-list

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to set 'isActive: false', and you don't need to bind isActive to each of the items. you can do as follows: 1, declare an array, called 'candidates', then each item clicked will be pushed into candidates.  2, declare a function, called 'contains()' which checks if an item is in the candidates array. 3, bind contains() to each item. 4, in CSS, give 'clicked' some style.

html code:

```
<body>
    <div id="toolBtns">
        <button v-for="item in buttons" v-on:click="provide(item)" v-bind:class="{clicked: contains(candidates, item)}" type="button">{{ item.name }}
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

javascript code:

```
var toolBtns = new Vue({
el: '#toolBtns',
data: 
{
    buttons: [
        {name: 'Btn1'},
        {name: 'Btn2'},
        {name: 'Btn3'},
    ],
    candidates: [],
},
methods:
{
    provide: function(item)
    {
        if(this.candidates.indexOf(item) == -1)
        {
            this.candidates.push(item);
        }
        else
        {
             this.candidates.splice(this.candidates.indexOf(item), 1);
        }
    },
    contains: function(arr, item)
    {
        return arr.indexOf(item) != -1;
    },
}
});
```

CSS code

```
.clicked{
    background-color: red;
}
```

here is the jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/JoyAndBrave/anzdzq4L/6/

Answer (score 1):

The direction of the solution above is correct but it's very vulnerable to errors since it uses indexes directly. 
As suggested in the answer above, doing a v-for would basically solve your problem.

```
var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#toolBtns',
 data: {
    buttons:[{name:'Btn1',active:false},{name:'Btn2',active:false},
            {name:'Btn3',active:false}]
 },
 methods: {
   toggleActiveClass:function(index){
     this.buttons[index].active=!this.buttons[index].active;
   }
  }
});


 <div class="btn-group" role="group" id="toolBtns">
   <button v-for="(btn, index) in buttons" type="button" 
               @click="toggleActiveClass(index)"
              :class="{active: btn.active}">{{btn.name}}
   </button>
 </div>
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/547/

Comment: Thank you Cristi Jora :)
The solution is successful. But only one button had to be active in each click.

Comment: Oh didn't read about that. Then upon toggleActiveClass you just have to disable all other buttons :) 
Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/549/

Comment: Thank you. The solution is exactly what I want