# How can I add button selected if clicked on the box list?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, vue-component

I get reference from here :

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/card/#card-groups

https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/button/#pressed-state-and-toggling

My vue component like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <b-card-group deck v-for="row in formattedItems">
            <b-card :title="item.title"
                    img-src="http://placehold.it/140?text=No image"
                    img-alt="Img"
                    img-top
                    v-for="item in row">
                <p class="card-text">
                    {{item.price}}
                </p>
                <p class="card-text">
                    {{item.country}}
                </p>
                <div slot="footer">
                    <b-button-group size="sm">
                        <b-button :pressed.sync="oriPress" variant="outline-primary">Original</b-button>
                        <b-button :pressed.sync="kwPress" variant="outline-primary">Kw</b-button>
                    </b-button-group>
                    <b-btn variant="primary" block>Add</b-btn>
                </div>
            </b-card>
        </b-card-group>
    ....
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        ..
        data () {
            return{
                items: [
                     {id:1, title:'chelsea', price:900, country: 'england'},
                     {id:2, title:'liverpool', price:800, country: 'england'},
                     {id:3, title:'mu', price:700, country: 'england'},
                     {id:4, title:'city', price:600, country: 'england'},
                     {id:5, title:'arsenal', price:500, country: 'england'},
                     {id:6, title:'tottenham', price:400, country: 'england'},
                     {id:7, title:'juventus', price:300, country: 'italy'},
                     {id:8, title:'madrid', price:200, country: 'span'},
                     {id:9, title:'barcelona', price:100, country: 'span'},
                     {id:10, title:'psg', price:50, country: 'france'}
                ],
                oriPress: true,
                kwPress: false
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.getItems()
        },
        computed: {
            formattedItems() {
                return this.items.reduce((c, n, i) => {
                    if (i % 4 === 0) c.push([]);
                    c[c.length - 1].push(n);
                    return c;
                }, []);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If the script executed, button original in all box active and button kw in all box inactive

That is what I expected. But my problem is when I click the kw button or the original button, all buttons are active or inacive. I want it active only on the button selected on each box

For example there are 10 box boxes. When I click the original button in the third box, the original button in the third box will be active and the kw button will be inactive. When I click the button kw in the ninth box, the button kw in the ninth box will be active and the button original will be inactive. So do the others

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the same `oriPress` and `kwPress` data properties are used for all items. You could move those properties into `items[]` so that they're unique to each item:

```
// script
data() {
  return {
    items: [
      {id: 1, oriPress: true, kwPress: false, ...},
      {id: 2, oriPress: true, kwPress: false, ...},
    ]
  }
}

//template
<b-card-group v-for="row in formattedItems">
  <b-card v-for="item in row">

      <b-button :pressed.sync="item.oriPress">Original</b-button>
      <b-button :pressed.sync="item.kwPress">Kw</b-button>

  </b-card>
</b-card-group>
```

...but I assume the shape of `items[]` cannot be changed. The alternative is to create a map of `oriPress` and `kwPress` properties (one per item). This could be done with a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on `items[]` that initializes `oriPress` and `kwPress` each to a map of item IDs to Booleans:

```
// script
data() {
  return {
    items: [...],
    oriPress: {},
    kwPress: {},
  }
},
watch: {
  items: {
    immediate: true,
    handler(value) {
      this.oriPress = value.reduce((p,c) => {
        p[c.id] = true;
        return p;
      }, {});

      this.kwPress = value.reduce((p,c) => {
        p[c.id] = false;
        return p;
      }, {});
    }
  }
},


//template
<b-card-group v-for="row in formattedItems">
  <b-card v-for="item in row">

      <b-button :pressed.sync="oriPress[item.id]">Original</b-button>
      <b-button :pressed.sync="kwPress[item.id]">Kw</b-button>

  </b-card>
</b-card-group>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return{
      items: [
        {id:1, title:'chelsea', price:900, country: 'england'},
        {id:2, title:'liverpool', price:800, country: 'england'},
        {id:3, title:'mu', price:700, country: 'england'},
        {id:4, title:'city', price:600, country: 'england'},
        {id:5, title:'arsenal', price:500, country: 'england'},
        {id:6, title:'tottenham', price:400, country: 'england'},
        {id:7, title:'juventus', price:300, country: 'italy'},
        {id:8, title:'madrid', price:200, country: 'span'},
        {id:9, title:'barcelona', price:100, country: 'span'},
        {id:10, title:'psg', price:50, country: 'france'}
      ],
      oriPress: {},
      kwPress: {}
    }
  },
  watch: {
    items: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(value) {
        this.oriPress = value.reduce((p,c) => {
          p[c.id] = true;
          return p;
        }, {});
        this.kwPress = value.reduce((p,c) => {
          p[c.id] = false;
          return p;
        }, {});
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    formattedItems() {
      return this.items.reduce((c, n, i) => {
        if (i % 4 === 0) c.push([]);
        c[c.length - 1].push(n);
        return c;
      }, []);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-card-group deck v-for="row in formattedItems">
    <b-card :title="item.title"
            img-src="http://placehold.it/140?text=No image"
            img-alt="Img"
            img-top
            v-for="item in row">
      <p class="card-text">
        {{item.price}}
      </p>
      <p class="card-text">
        {{item.country}}
      </p>
      <div slot="footer">
        <b-button-group size="sm">
          <b-button :pressed.sync="oriPress[item.id]" variant="outline-primary">Original</b-button>
          <b-button :pressed.sync="kwPress[item.id]" variant="outline-primary">Kw</b-button>
        </b-button-group>
        <b-btn variant="primary" block>Add</b-btn>
      </div>
    </b-card>
  </b-card-group>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. But I want to ask. Can it be in a box when the original button is active, the kw button is inactive? Vice versa

Comment: The shape of `items[]` can be changed. So I can add key `oriPress` and `kwPress` in the items array.

Comment: I don't understand your question about "it being in a box". What do you mean?

Comment: I mean in each box, if the original button is clicked, the original  button is active, the kw button is inactive. If the kw button is clicked, the kw button is active, the original button is inactive

Comment: Oh, I see. That would be implemented with [button style radios](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-radio/#button-style-radios), which would require a different solution than what you have.

Comment: Yes that's what I mean

Comment: That would be better answered in a new question, since it's not directly related to this question. Please ask a new question so that others could provide a detailed answer for you. :)

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot. I will make a new question

Comment: Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52568601/how-can-i-add-link-in-the-card-deck-groups